# Rails: Marking a record as read?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app in which I need to keep track of the first time and the most recent time a certain user role viewed a record. I am new to Rails, but my approach so far is to have an `after_action` that calls a method to set the read status, like this:

```
after_action :set_read_status, only: :show
```

Here is `set_read_status`:

```
def set_read_status
  if current_user.role == 'site_user'
    @record.first_read = DateTime.current
    @record.latest_read = DateTime.current
    @record.save!
  end
end
```

But it's doing several unexpected things:

In my RSpec file, when I test this method with a different user role, it should NOT set these values, but it is doing so. This code:

```
expect( assigns(:record).first_read ).to be_nil
expect( assigns(:record).latest_read ).to be_nil
```

Gets this result:

```
1) RecordsController GET #set_read_status non-site users does not update read status
 Failure/Error: expect( assigns(:record).first_read ).to be_nil

   expected: nil
        got: 2016-05-18 16:17:54.386616709 +0000
```

When I go to my records#index page and print those values, they're nil, but when I go to the records#show page, the value is set. AND, when I look at that record in the Rails console, the date is NOT set.

Why would Rails think this value was nil on one page but display a date on the other?

Also, this doesn't feel like a very Rails-y way to do it--I don't like gunking up my Record model with these values. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

When you use after_action:

```
after_action :set_read_status, only: :show
```

That works only for one action `show`. If you want to run your code in index too you have to specify it:

```
after_action :set_read_status, only: [:show, :index]
```

Of course in `index` action you probably have `@records` instead of `@record` so you have to adjust your method `set_read_status`.

Maybe think about separate class that will handle marking your records according to your roles policy. You can even create separated model to persist your users interaction with your records.

Regarding `Rspec` test you have to be aware that they are using `test` environment, and not `development` environment, so they create separate database etc.

Comment: Yes, it should only be for `show`. But in my example above, the `after_action` should have no effect at all unless the user has that role. But the app was showing different values for the same property of the same record-- `nil` on the index page, and a datetime on the show page. And then `nil` again when I go back to index.

Comment: In Rspec test scenarios? Maybe you don't save your object to the database or you recreate that object every time you run new scenario. In development you may use byebug to watch your controller execution. See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-byebug-gem

Comment: Seeing the same behavior in rspec test environment and in development.

Comment: Err... that's strange.. Could you edit your question and add models and controllers code?